# Which bipartite entangled states violate the CHSH maximally?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I am reading the [device independent outlook on quantum mechanics](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.3081). Here the author gives a proof that for two qubit system maximally entangled states violate the CHSH inequality maximally that is upto $2\sqrt{2}$ for suitable measurements. Is it true for higher dimension bipartite states also ? ( I know all bipartite entangled states of any dimension do violate CHSH inequality for suitable measurements ).

Comment: Another quantum mystic article that ends up where it starts: chasing its own tail. Quantum physics doesn't need to be "derived from physical principles" any more than classical mechanics. All of physics is derived from observations of nature. Seriously, you need to get yourself some better reading material.

Comment: @CuriousOne I respect your views as you are an experienced user and I am just a beginner in QM. But I read about quantum mysticism from wiki and it has no relation at all to my question or to my reading material. All the author shows is QM can't be explained by hidden variable theory ( to the point I have read ), I don't find anything mystic about it.

Comment: @CuriousOne The usual analogy here is with special relativity, which can be "derived" from essentially symmetry arguments. While I agree with you that such a derivation is not necessary since observation is the only true foundation of scientific theories, it is certainly not inconceivable that such an argument could exist, and it would at least have pedagogical value. So I don't think it is quite fair to rubbish that research goal out of hand.

Comment: In his abstract the author clearly says that he wants to "derive" quantum mechanics from "physical principles". The rules of quantum mechanics are physical principles. All you are getting from that paper on the following pages are lame repeats of things that others have said and done before and better.

Comment: @MarkMitchison: Special relativity can not be derived any more than any other theory. Nature selects which principles her systems follow, we observe and then we learn the math that is the most suitable description. Einstein didn't "derive" anything in his papers. He already knew the correct answers from experiments that had been done 20 years earlier. The only question that was left to answer in 1905 was how to integrate mechanics. That, of course, is not how the author of this paper proceeds who labors under the false impression that the measurement process can be eliminated.

Comment: @CuriousOne You think "a quantum state is represented by a ray in a Hilbert space" is a physical principle? I think we are talking about different things here. The principles people should be interested in are *operational*, e.g. all observers moving with constant velocity w.r.t. each other measure light to move at $c$. I don't know what interests the author of that paper since, like you, I don't waste my time reading such work. In any case, my comment simply suggested there may be some pedagogical value in quantum foundations (read "mysticism"), I'm not foolish enough to try convincing you.

Comment: @MarkMitchison: You think a force represented by an arrow is a physical principle? I am talking about science, i.e. the rational description of nature, while you seem to be talking about some weird pre-determined philosophical morass where everything follows from nothing. That doesn't even happen in mathematics that way. All definitions in physics are operational, more precisely they are comparisons against physical standards. If you dare to set a foot into a working experimental physics lab you will actually be able to experience just how operational a real quantum measurement is.

Comment: @CuriousOne That may be, but some physical principles are more commonly and easily stated in a manifestly operational way than others. Hence there is pedagogical value in trying to find a way to state them *all* in a manifestly operational manner. By the way, if you ever dare to speak to anyone outside of the high-energy community you might find the world of physics outside is a bit less segregated between theorists and experimentalists than you imagine.

Comment: @MarkMitchison: The operational ways in which physical effects are stated properly is in the experimental setups at NIST and other standard labs. Everything else in physics derives from what those guys are doing trough a chain of engineering normals that transport the basic quantities to the place of the actual measurement. I know that we aren't teaching the reality of physical experiments enough, but every physicist should know what an experiment actually is: it's a comparison of the unknown against the known.